# Why does my HTML form's action tag ignore it's other GET-variables generated by JSP?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, url, action

I have a HTML form whose action tag redirects to the same page, with appended variables generated by JSP (the variables print existing variables), but when I use the form it only shows the current URL with only the variable from the form, so the other, JSP generated, variables are missing. My (simplified) form looks like this:

```
<form id="tfnewsort" method="get" action="./index.jsp?categorie=<% out.println(categorie); %>&minprijs=<% out.println(stringminprijs); %>&maxprijs=<% out.println(stringmaxprijs); %>">
  <select name="sorteermethode" id="sortselect">
    <option value="date_added">
      Datum oplopend
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

As you can see, it should redirect to a URL created by printing some variables and appending it's own variable ("sorteermethode") to the end of the URL. Now, when I actually use it, it redirects to something like 'http://localhost:8080/webshop/index.jsp?sorteermethode=name', essentially ignoring the other variables and replacing it by it's own variable, instead of appending it to the end of the URL. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong (besides using JSP scriplets) and/or how to solve this?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm surprised nobody suggested using POST for a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as `hidden` input fields, as both the query string and the `<form>`'s method is also `GET`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="categorie" value="<% out.println(categorie); %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="minprijs" value="<% out.println(stringminprijs); %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="maxprijs" value="<% out.println(stringmaxprijs); %>" />
```

Comment: Sure thing! Unfortunately, I've now stumbled upon my next issue. The hidden fields mess up the variables pretty badly. My URL now rolls out like this: http://localhost:8080/bosstamps/index.jsp?sorteermethode=price&categorie=Category%3B%25%0D%0A&minprijs=0.00%0D%0A&maxprijs=10.00%0D%0A. It adds a lot of percent signs and random number. Could you help me this by any chance?

Comment: The hidden fields in the form should be generating normal string GET-variables, like 'Category;Postzegels' (which specifies of which category to display items). Instead, they now produce weird strings in the URL, like Category%3B%25%0D%0A. It also does this for the other variables generated by the JSP in the hidden fields. These values are, therefore, unusable by my JSP.

Comment: Don't worry, they are escaped variables... If you go to WikiPedia in any other language than English, eg. Greek or Hindi, the URL looks like that and it is completely normal for making the unicode characters work with the address bar. Do you understand?

Comment: I think I understand. Is there a way of converting this back to the original string, as generated by the JSP used in the hidden fields? JSP doesn't do this automatically, and therefore renders the values useless and doesn't display any items (since there aren't any categories named Category%3B%25%0D%0A).

Comment: Is there a (JSP) function I can use to decode the strings?

Comment: There are lots... In lot of languages. Lemme grab one for you.

Answer (score 1):

The form data generates a new query string. This replaces the existing one.

If you want to put extra data in it, then put it in hidden input elements instead of the action.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the other variables as hidden input elements. The point of GET is to add all the input values to the querystring, it does not merge them with the current action.